# Is it possible to install a repository via a web (Clicking in a webpage link)

Tags: add-apt-repository

I know it is possible to install an app from the Software Center via clicking an **apt** link in a web page. But is it possible to install a repository by clicking also?

For example when a user clicks on a link it does this:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` but by clicking on a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apturl` (the magic program that handles `apt://` URLs) does have code to handle `apt+http://` URLs like this:

```
apt+http://launchpad.net/~oli/ppa?package=olis-package
```

Which would theoretically add that PPA, install that package and then (if the user wanted it), leave that PPA installed.

### But `apturl`'s manpage currently says this is disabled:

> Warning: This is currently disabled because of security concerns.

I've just tested it and it does appear to be disabled. I can understand the security issue. Having people install software from PPAs is enough of a security issue let along making it a 1-click operation.

The alternative for people who want to release a PPA for their own software is to write a dummy-package that adds the PPA and installs the other packages. You either make that .deb available on your website or you could ask for it to be added to the universe. Then it really would be a 1-click thing.

Comment: I thought it was more complicated than a simple apt+ lol. Thanks.

Comment: It is more complicated than this apt+http links because (per the huge bold text in the middle of my post) it has been disabled. If you try a link like that, `apturl` just ignores the repository... But my alternative should make it as simple as it gets (without getting people to copy and paste things around)