# Run a line command from a web (Clicking in a webpage link)

Tags: apt

Is it possible to execute a command from a single link?

For example when a user clicks on a link it does this:

`sudo apt-get install vlc wine openshot` but by clicking on a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particular example is possible via the apt-uris:

```
http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wine
```

This will open wine in the software centre, giving the user the *option* to install it.

Running arbitrary commands on any Ubuntu machine is (hopefully) never possible:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution

Comment: I think I'm right in saying that apt.ubuntu.com is the preferred way of linking packages. The [AptUrl](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptUrl) wiki page is rather old :-)

Comment: What about the answer I posted above. Does it work for multiple programs or not since i took it from the Wiki about AptUrl.

Comment: Just read your answer. what about an example of installing multiple programs.

Comment: Installing multiple programs with one click doesn't work with this syntax I don't think

Answer (score 0):

Lol found it thanks to Oli's post here [Is it possible to install a repository via a web (Clicking in a webpage link)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47850/is-it-possible-to-install-a-repository-via-a-web-clicking-in-a-webpage-link)

It is possible to install multiple packages. In this wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptUrl all the possible actions can be found. To install one would be like this:

```
<a href="apt:package">click</a>
```

For example:

```
<a href="apt:vlc">click</a>
```

This would install vlc.

But lets say you want to install VLC, Ubuntu  Extras and subdownloader:

```
<a href="apt:vlc,ubuntu-restricted-extras,subdownloader">click</a>
```

Each separated by a comma. Awesome.